# What is the difference between a list and a multiset?

Tags: data-structures

From my understanding, both lists and multisets are collections of ordered values in which values can occur more than once. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, lists and multisets are different. Order matters in lists, and doesn't in multisets.

```
(list 1 2 3 2) != (list 2 1 3 2)
(multiset 1 2 2 3) == (multiset 1 3 2 2)
```

Comment: so whats the difference between a `multiset` and an `unordered_multiset` then?

Comment: My answer is for the generic, mathematical definitions of list and multiset. Seems like you are referring to the C++ `multiset` and `unordered_multiset`. In C++, `multiset` is actually an ordered multiset, where elements are stored in sorted order. (akin to high a C++ `set` actually stores elements in sorted order as well)

Comment: Pandas describes index of series as an "ordered mutli-set". Doesn't it just mean an array? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html

Answer (score 6):

Besides order, each container has it own set of available methods and their complexity.
For example, searching in a list is `o(n)` (you'll have to check every element until you find the one). Searching in `multiset` is `o(log(n))`. It is usually implemented as a red-black tree to fit this requirement

Comment: But how does the red black tree justify repeating elements? Is it just an extra counter in the node for a value?